# Regex XML with group name and including tags

Tags: regex, xml, splunk

I have a XML that looks like this

```
Executing request: POST https://[website]:
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8 standalone=yes?><request>[data]</request>
```

Id like to regex out everything, including the request open and closing tags and name the group raw_message but I can't figure out how to do that. I've used regex101 and it makes sense but doesn't match and the debugger hasn't helped me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: As Michael Kay says, drop the idea of doing that with regular expressions, it's a bad idea. When you say what software you're using, we can give you a recommendation what else to use.

Comment: I’m using Splunk and events from there

Comment: I don't have enough experience with Splunk to write a full-blown answer, but [Splunk has XPath support](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/8.0.2003/SearchReference/xpath).  XPath is the right tool to extract data from XML.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions to process XML, always use an XML parser; for transforming XML, use XSLT (or XQuery if appropriate). Using regular expressions, unless you are very smart, can give horrible performance problems, but more importantly, they will always be wrong. Even if they work on all your test cases, it is always possible to devise a sample XML document that defeats them. (If you want to know why, this is because XML is not a "regular language" in the computer science sense of the term: it's a recursive language, and regular expressions don't do recursion.)